# How do I get the error message in Oracle SQL Developer to display the line number?

Tags: sql, oracle, error-handling

I'm running version 4.1.2.20 on the mac, and I'm getting an error on a long query:

**Error converting data type varchar to numeric.**

How do I get it to display the line number the query is hitting the error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1589252/is-there-a-way-to-get-the-line-number-where-an-exception-was-thrown

Comment: if it's an db response error, it should show as ORA-00905: missing keyword
00905. 00000 -  "missing keyword"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 16 Column: 7, as an example. provide your code and I can give a better answer, maybe.

Comment: You're using SQL Developer to connect to a SQL Server database?